# libnotify with bash and grep

Tags: command-line, grep, libnotify, notify-send

I am trying to get libnotify (notify-send) to pop-up a notification once a certain character is found while I tail a log file.

Without grep it works fine ...

Here is my code:

```
 tail -f /var/log/mylogfile | grep ">" | while read line; do notify-send "CURRENT LOGIN" "$line" -t 3000; done
```

When I include grep it passes nothing to notify-send. The code above I modified from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1411620

Also, how can I change the font size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](http://blog.jpalardy.com/posts/grep-and-output-buffering/) explains grep and output buffering, in short you want to use the `--line-buffered` flag:

```
tail -f /var/log/mylogfile | grep --line-buffered ">" | while read line; do notify-send "CURRENT LOGIN" "$line" -t 3000; done
```

About the font, [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128474/how-to-customize-on-screen-notifications) mentions it's not officially possible, but describes a tool `notifyosdconfig` that allows some modifications.

Comment: That did the trick ... thank you ... the font is not really important ... just a little too small ...